# Measure of sets under linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to prove the following. Let $L: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation and $Q_0 = [0,1]^n$ be the unit cube. Let $d_l = |L(Q_0)|$. Prove that $|L(Q)| = d_l |Q|$ for every cube $Q \subseteq R^n$. Here $|-|$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

Now I have tried proving this but cannot seem to get far. Of course, since $L$ is Lipschitz we have $|L(Q)| \leq C|Q|$. However, I cannot get past this point. For context, this is the first subproblem that appears in a problem that proves that $|L(E)| = |det(L)||E|$ whenever $E$ is measurable.

Any help or hints is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that any positive, translation invariant measure on $\mathbb R^n$ that is finite on compact sets, is a constant multiple of Lebesgue measure? If so, let $\mu(E)=m(L(E))$

Comment: @Matematleta, I do not know this ...

Answer (score 1):

This is how Rudin does it:

if $L$ is not onto, then it maps $Q_0$ into a space of dimension strictly less than $n$ so $d_l=0.$ Otherwise, $L$ is a homeomorphism so $L(E)$ is Borel for each Borel set $E$.  In particular, $L(Q)$ is Borel, so $m\circ L$ is a well-defined measure. Now,

$\tag1 m(L(E+x))=m(L(E))+L(x))=m(L(E))$

because $m$ is translation-invariant. Then, since $Q_0$ is a disjoint union of $2^{nk}$ boxes $Q$ of volume $2^{-n},\ (1)$ imlplies that

$2^{nk}m(L(Q))=m(L(Q_0))=m(L(Q_0))\cdot 1=m(L(Q_0))\cdot m(Q_0)=$

$m(L(Q_0))\cdot (2^{nk}m(Q))$  so

$\tag2 m(L(Q))=m(L(Q_0))m(Q)$